# Detect language of browser -> Redirect one subpage to detected language version. How to do it in htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a calendar to book reservations. After fulfilling the form calendar is redirecting user to success page. It redirects user to same default language no matter what (in settings of plugi I chose specific page). I want to write redirect in htaccess which works like this:
Detect browser language
Redirect from [www.domain.com/success/](http://www.domain.com/success/) to [www.domain.com/en/success-en/](http://www.domain.com/en/success-en/)

I tried sth like this but does not seem to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^success/?$ $1//en/success-en/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^([a-z]{2}) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(success)/?$ /%1/$1-%1/ [R=301,L]
```